# What is problem in my texture rendering function and how I solve it?

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to make a 2D texture rendering function in pygame. But it doesn't work. Here is function:

```py
def drawTexture(screen,texture,rect):
    last_texture_x, last_texture_y = rect[2],rect[3]
    for texture_count_y in range(0,int(rect[3]/texture.get_height())+1):
        for texture_count_x in range(0,int(rect[2]/texture.get_width())+1):
            screen.blit(texture.subsurface(0,0,min(last_texture_x,texture.get_width()),min(last_texture_y,texture.get_height())),(rect[0]+texture.get_width()*texture_count_x,rect[1]+texture.get_height()*texture_count_y))
            last_texture_x -= texture.get_width()
        last_texture_y -= texture.get_height()
```

This function fills a rect with a texture. It fills width well. But it don't fill height when rect height is bigger than texture height. I think problem is `texture_count_y` variable. When I replace the variable to a number manually, the function works. But variable returns right value when I print it. My head really confused right now. How can I make the function works well?

**EDIT:**

[image]

Red lines mean rect.
Yellow lines mean texture images function uses to fill rect.
It fills columns well but it fills one row.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information on what exactly is the method/way you are generating the texture or expect it to generate?

Comment: Perhaps if you have some output info or images of what it renders and what it should, they might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple. `last_texture_x` must be initialized before the inner loop:

```py
def drawTexture(screen, texture, rect):
    last_texture_y = rect[3]
    for texture_count_y in range(0,int(rect[3]/texture.get_height())+1):
        last_texture_x = rect[2]
        for texture_count_x in range(0,int(rect[2]/texture.get_width())+1):
                screen.blit(texture.subsurface(0,0,min(last_texture_x,texture.get_width()),min(last_texture_y,texture.get_height())),(rect[0]+texture.get_width()*texture_count_x,rect[1]+texture.get_height()*texture_count_y))
                last_texture_x -= texture.get_width()
        last_texture_y -= texture.get_height()
```

However, I recommend to use the features of the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clip) object for this task:

```py
def drawTexture(screen, texture, rect):
    target_rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
    for x in range(target_rect.left, target_rect.right, texture.get_width()):
        for y in range(target_rect.top, target_rect.bottom, texture.get_height()):
            clip_rect = texture.get_rect(topleft = (x, y)).clip(target_rect)
            screen.blit(texture.subsurface(0, 0, *clip_rect.size), (x, y))
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def drawTexture(screen, texture, rect):
    target_rect = pygame.Rect(rect)
    for x in range(target_rect.left, target_rect.right, texture.get_width()):
        for y in range(target_rect.top, target_rect.bottom, texture.get_height()):
            clip_rect = texture.get_rect(topleft = (x, y)).clip(target_rect)
            screen.blit(texture.subsurface(0, 0, *clip_rect.size), (x, y))

target_rect = pygame.Rect(25, 25, 450, 250)
texture = pygame.Surface((200, 200))
texture.fill((255, 255, 0))
pygame.draw.rect(texture, (127, 127, 127), (2, 2, 196, 196))

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False      

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), target_rect, 5)
    drawTexture(window, texture, target_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I understood my wrong.